# Java открытие файла, созданного вне приложения

Tags: java, android, файлы

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь написать приложение для Android (в данном случае для 6.0). Возникла проблема в процессе реализации:
Нужно открыть файл, который не был создан приложением. Переместить файл в нужную директорию (а именно в директорию приложений) - не проблема. Проблема в том, что приложение может открыть только тот файл, который был заранее создан этим приложением. При попытке открыть любые другие файлы получаю Permission denied. Причём в манифесте выставлены разрешения на чтение/запись с карточки (будто это помогает), в телефоне все галочки на разрешениях установлены. Есть ли какие-то способы открытия такого файла для чтения?

```
void writeFile() {
    try {
        // отрываем поток для записи

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(FILENAME)));
        String line = "";
        String FileContent = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            FileContent = FileContent + line + NL;
        }
        br.close();
        FileContent = FileContent.replaceAll("(H|h)(E|e)(L|l)(L|l)(O|o)",
                "1234");
        System.out.println(FileContent);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
        bw.write(FileContent);
        bw.close();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Файл записан");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пытался считывать файлы, все работало нормально до того как протестил на 6.0 девайсе.
С версии 6.0 вводится фича такая: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

```
if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Context ctx,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ) != 0) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity act,
                        new String[]Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Считать файл с sd_карты:

```
final String EXPANSION = ".txt"; //расширение файла
final String FILENAME_SD = "file" + EXPANSION; //имя файла
final String DIR_SD = "MyFiles";  //папка на sd-карте, в которой лежит ваш файл

void readFileSD() {
// проверяем доступность SD
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
  return;
}
// получаем путь к SD
File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// добавляем свой каталог к пути
sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
// формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу
File sdFile = new File(sdPath, FILENAME_SD);
try {
  // открываем поток для чтения
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sdFile));
  String str = "";
  // читаем содержимое
  while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);   //выводим содержимое в лог
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Осталось в манифест добавить разрешение на работу с файлами на SD -

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
```

Вот, собственно говоря и весь код))